# robocopy adding /s automatically

Tags: robocopy

Hi I'm new to robocopy and need a little help. I know its really long but this is my batch file.

robocopy "c:\users\olsen" "z:\trial" /z /e /fft /r:3 /w:2 /log+:z:\trial\log\backup.txt /xa:sh /tee /mt:32 /xjd /np /xd *cookies *"application data" *contacts *downloads *favorites *links *onedrive *"saved games" *searches *videos *appdata

I'm trying to copy empty folders. Everything works great (almost) but it doesn't copy my empty folders. When i run my batch file and the command prompt screen shows my options this is what it shows

Options : *.* /FFT /TEE **/S** /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /Z /NP /XJD /XA:SH /MT:32 /R:3 /W:2

(I bolded the "/s") Is one of my other switches turning this on or is robocopy just playing with me? Everything is transferring perfectly other than the empty files. I'm guessing that the /s is canceling out my /e.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Jeremy

Comment: What do you mean by 'copy empty folders'? Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Directory. Sorry the icons look like folders. I haven't gotten used to calling them directories.

Comment: I have directories for future years and months set up 2017 jan-Dec, 2018 jan-dec on my main computer so files can be backed up without setting up a new directory each month. I'd like to have those empty directories replicated on my backup location. That is why I was trying to use the /e switch but the directories aren't being replicated like I'd like them. I think it is because the /s switch is showing up in the options despite me not including it in the batch file.

Comment: Seeing "/S" when I do "/E" has been also puzzling me ... do you have an answer ? You could also separate the two questions: the mysterious "/S" option and the empty folders (files) not copied.