# Does robocopy always add the option "/S" for "/E"?

Tags: windows-10, robocopy

When I do

```
robocopy ./empty_folders ./empty_folders_dest /E
```

I see the following options:

```
Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
```

How does the argument `/S` (excludes empty directories) get in there, logically excluded by `/E` (includes empty directories)? The reciprocal is (logically) not true: when I do `/S` I do not see `/E`.

Further details:

```
wmic datafile where name="C:\\Windows\\System32\\robocopy.exe" get Version /value
Version=10.0.16299.15

ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.125]
```

Comment: The question is already included in a larger unanswered question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984828/robocopy-adding-s-automatically

Comment: I guess the documentation is maybe wrong: `/S` simply copies non-empty subdirectories, while `/E` implies `/S` and the empty subdirectories.

Comment: ... the documentation being here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand the documentation.  Run "robocopy /???" to see the full built in help.

> ```
> /S :: copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones.
> /E :: copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.
> ```

In other words, /S will copy subdirectories **except** for empty ones. /E will copy subdirectories **including** empty ones.

Comment: Yes, there was a mistake, I inverted the explanations for `/S` and `/E`. But the questions (though more understandable) stands: `/E` implies  `/S`, why have both ? It is a little bit confusing ...

Comment: @Liviu You would simply choose one: `/E` or `/S` depending on whether you wanted to copy empty subdirectories or not.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same situation when I use /MIR switch but without it, these two switches are not automatically added. So I suggest this situation may be related to other used switches.

Robocopy with /MIR switch:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ROBOCOPY F:\robocopytestv G:\robocopytestw /MIR

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Friday, February 8, 2019 19:40:01
   Source : F:\robocopytestv\
     Dest : G:\robocopytestw\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           6    F:\robocopytestv\
100%        New File                   0        New Bitmap Image.bmp
100%        New File              495616        New Microsoft Access Database.accdb
100%        New File                6171        New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx
100%        New File                   0        New Microsoft PowerPoint Presentation.pptx
100%        New File                   0        New Microsoft Word Document.docx
100%        New File                7942        New OpenDocument Drawing.odg
          New Dir          0    F:\robocopytestv\New folder\

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         2         1         1         0         0         0
   Files :         6         6         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :   497.7 k   497.7 k         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :            72818428 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :            4166.703 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : Friday, February 8, 2019 19:40:01
```

Robocopy without /MIR switch:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ROBOCOPY F:\robocopytestv G:\robocopytestw

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Friday, February 8, 2019 19:38:12
   Source : F:\robocopytestv\
     Dest : G:\robocopytestw\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           6    F:\robocopytestv\
100%        New File                   0        New Bitmap Image.bmp
100%        New File              495616        New Microsoft Access Database.accdb
100%        New File                6171        New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx
100%        New File                   0        New Microsoft PowerPoint Presentation.pptx
100%        New File                   0        New Microsoft Word Document.docx
100%        New File                7942        New OpenDocument Drawing.odg

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
   Files :         6         6         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :   497.7 k   497.7 k         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :            84954833 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :            4861.154 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : Friday, February 8, 2019 19:38:12
```

Robocopy with /MIR and /S switches:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ROBOCOPY F:\robocopytestv G:\robocopytestw /S /MIR

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Friday, February 8, 2019 19:41:17
   Source : F:\robocopytestv\
     Dest : G:\robocopytestw\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           6    F:\robocopytestv\
100%        New File                   0        New Bitmap Image.bmp
100%        New File              495616        New Microsoft Access Database.accdb
100%        New File                6171        New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx
100%        New File                   0        New Microsoft PowerPoint Presentation.pptx
100%        New File                   0        New Microsoft Word Document.docx
100%        New File                7942        New OpenDocument Drawing.odg
          New Dir          0    F:\robocopytestv\New folder\

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         2         1         1         0         0         0
   Files :         6         6         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :   497.7 k   497.7 k         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :            12432414 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :             711.388 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : Friday, February 8, 2019 19:41:18
```

Robocopy with /MIR and /E switches:

```
C:\Windows\system32>ROBOCOPY F:\robocopytestv G:\robocopytestw /E /MIR

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Friday, February 8, 2019 19:42:35
   Source : F:\robocopytestv\
     Dest : G:\robocopytestw\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           6    F:\robocopytestv\
100%        New File                   0        New Bitmap Image.bmp
100%        New File              495616        New Microsoft Access Database.accdb
100%        New File                6171        New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx
100%        New File                   0        New Microsoft PowerPoint Presentation.pptx
100%        New File                   0        New Microsoft Word Document.docx
100%        New File                7942        New OpenDocument Drawing.odg
          New Dir          0    F:\robocopytestv\New folder\

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         2         1         1         0         0         0
   Files :         6         6         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :   497.7 k   497.7 k         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :            72818428 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :            4166.703 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : Friday, February 8, 2019 19:42:35
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) states that `/MIR` is `/E` + `/purge`, therefore `/S` will be added, so there's nothing new here (by rapport to the initial question), but thanks anyway!